# Limit amount of rows used by average

Tags: sql, postgresql, limit

I've a query (postgresql) where I'd like to limit the rows used for computing the average

```
SELECT username,avg(income),count(*) FROM
       Events 
WHERE to_timestamp(eventtimestamp)  >=  '2008-02-23' AND 
      to_timestamp(eventtimestamp) <=   '2009-01-03' and username='Joe'
GROUP BY userid
```

Joe has 40 entries but I want to limit the amount of rows used to compute the average of his income. I'm aware of the **limit** function I could add at the end of the query but this limits the output of the *whole* query instead of the rows considered by the **average** command in the head of the query. Any hints how I could tell avg to use only first n rows?

e.g. **not working**

```
SELECT username,avg(income) limit 5,count(*) FROM
       Events 
WHERE to_timestamp(eventtimestamp)  >=  '2008-02-23' AND 
      to_timestamp(eventtimestamp) <=   '2009-01-03' and username='Joe'
GROUP BY userid
```

to average only over the first 5 rows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding an answer for two reasons.  First, most of the other answers affect the `count(*)` as well as the `avg()`, which is not part of the question.  Second, you may want to do this for more than one user.

So, you can try the following:

```
SELECT username, avg(case when seqnum <= 40 then income end), count(*)
FROM (select e.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by username order by eventtimestamp desc) as seqnum
      from Events e
      WHERE to_timestamp(eventtimestamp)  >=  '2008-02-23' AND 
            to_timestamp(eventtimestamp) <=   '2009-01-03'
     ) e
GROUP BY username
```

Comment: The case is missing `else null end`

Comment: Other than that I think it is the only correct answer according to the OP's literal requirements.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Excellent point re. count(*) and good expansion for more than one user. Minor optimization: if there isn't an index on `to_timstamp(eventtimestamp)`, I'd change so we don't execute function for every row as follows: `WHERE eventtimestamp BETWEEN date_part('epoch', '2008-02-23'::date) AND date_part('epoch', '2009-01-03'::date)`

Answer (score 2):

You can take the average of an inner query:

```
SELECT username,avg(income),count(*)
FROM (
  SELECT username, income
  FROM Events 
  WHERE to_timestamp(eventtimestamp) BETWEEN '2008-02-23' AND '2009-01-03'
  and username='Joe'
  LIMIT 5) x
GROUP BY userid;
```

Also note the simplification by using `BETWEEN`

Comment: Good - you'll want to add an `ORDER BY` clause to limit rows.

Comment: The `count(*)` will always be <= 5. It is not clear from the question if is that what the OP wants. I suspect it is the total count.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use limit in a subselect;

```
SELECT username,avg(income),count(*) FROM
  (SELECT * FROM Events 
   WHERE to_timestamp(eventtimestamp)  >=  '2008-02-23' AND 
      to_timestamp(eventtimestamp) <=   '2009-01-03' and username='Joe'
   order by to_timestamp(eventtimestamp) desc
   LIMIT 10) sub
GROUP BY userid;
```

Comment: The `count(*)` will always be <= 10. It is not clear from the question if is that what the OP wants. I suspect it is the total count.

Answer (score 1):

If by chance you prefer (or don't care) the average over the 5 rows finishing with the current one you can avoid the subselect using a window function:

```
select
    username,
    avg(income) over(rows 4 preceding),
    count(*)
from events 
where to_timestamp(eventtimestamp)  >=  '2008-02-23' and 
      to_timestamp(eventtimestamp) <=   '2009-01-03' and username='joe'
group by userid
```

If I understand your comment you can indeed use `count` as a window function:

```
    count(*) over(rows 4 preceding)
```

Or if don't want to count nulls:

```
    count(income) over(rows 4 preceding)
```

Comment: That would be my preferred way because I've a set of queries that I have to change like you suggested. The only problem with that solution is that count(*) is not effected by the row limitation. Unfortunately, adding over() to count(*) doesn't work ;(

Comment: I tried that but *count* changes to 1 as soon as I add **count(*) over(rows X preceding)**. No matter if X=1 or X=1000000, the count columns remains 1 after adding the over()

Comment: @Durin How many rows there are for `username='joe'` within that time frame?

Comment: @Durin Also are you limiting the output? Because count will always be 1 for the first row.

Comment: username='joe' has 40 entries within that time frame. If I limit the *count( * ) over(rows 4 preceding)* then I would expect that count=4 but it is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Good answers already posted. I'd suggest doing the comparison and sort using the Unix epoch as follows:

```
SELECT userid, username, avg(income), count(*)
FROM (
  SELECT userid, username, income
  FROM Events 
  WHERE eventtimestamp BETWEEN date_part('epoch', '2008-02-23'::date) 
      AND date_part('epoch', '2009-01-03'::date)
    AND username='Joe'
  ORDER BY eventtimestamp DESC LIMIT 10) AS q
GROUP BY userid, username;
```

By doing this, I'm not calling the conversion function for each row. An alternative might be to create a functional index on `to_timestamp(eventtimestamp)` but I think the way I've done it is more efficient.

Note that I've included both userid and username - the original example would have thrown an error since username was not in the 'GROUP BY' clause.

As aside, if you wanted to calculate from a random sample rather than the last *n* entries, you could change the sort to `ORDER BY random()`

Comment: Same problem as other answers. The count(*) will always be <= 10. It is not clear from the question if it is that what the OP wants. I suspect it is the total count